# Saving SSN for background checks

Tags: mysql, database, security, encryption

What is the best process to save SSN (social security numbers) to be able to run a background check? Our background check provider needs them and they don't have a really good way of us to auto send the file over.  What is the industry standard for this?

Comment: we use linode so i can ask them

Comment: How do you send them to your background check provider? The answer is probably that you should save them in the most inaccessible fashion possible that will still allow you to get them to the provider when they need them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Social Security Numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/254935/storing-social-security-numbers).  Also consider reading http://www.ssa.gov/kc/id_practices_best.htm